# C -- file input reading issue

Tags: c, file-io, string-formatting, scanf

I'm reading in from a file `emp` and it was reading when the file (which is the last file below -- which worked) was structured as 10 records with a header (being skipped by the `fseek()` of 0 in the code).  But when it reads in with the 3x10 format (which is the middle file below, which failed to read properly) with headers for each block of 3 -- that's failing.  I'm not sure why the conditional just within the loop isn't catching and the 2nd conditional within the loop isn't printing everything marked with a 0 upfront.

```
    int   nDeleteSwitch;
    char  sSSN[10], sName[21];
    float nSalary;
    char nextIn[3];

    printf("SSN        NAME                 SALARY\n");

    mioHashFile = fopen("emp", "r");
    fscanf (mioHashFile,"%d",&mnOverFlowRecords);
    fseek (mioHashFile, mnHeaderSize, 0); //Skip past the CRLF at end of overflow counter

    //int numHeadRec = mnOverFlowRecords/3;
    /* sequentially print all active records */
    //for(int i=0;i<(numHeadRec+mnOverFlowRecords);i++)
    for(int i=0;i<20+mnOverFlowRecords;i++)
    {
        if ((fscanf(mioHashFile,"%d",nextIn)== -1) || (fscanf(mioHashFile,"%d",nextIn)== 0) ||
            (fscanf(mioHashFile,"%d",nextIn)== 1))
        {
            fscanf(mioHashFile,"%d%s%s%f",&nDeleteSwitch,sSSN,sName,&nSalary);
            //printf("%d",nDeleteSwitch);
            if (nDeleteSwitch==0)printf("%-11s%-21s%-10.2f\n",sSSN,sName,nSalary);  // wtf why this isn't printing 
            else if (nDeleteSwitch == -1) printf("there's a -1 on row: %d",i);
        }
        else {continue;};
    }
        fclose(mioHashFile);
        printf("Print Table Complete\n");
```

And here we have emp file that it's refusing to read the `0` entries from:

```
   0
Overflow page: 0 0 -1 
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
  0         x                    x      0.00
Overflow page: 1 0 -1 
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
  0         x                    x      0.00
Overflow page: 2 0 -1 
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
Overflow page: 3 0 -1 
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
Overflow page: 4 0 -1 
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
Overflow page: 5 0 -1 
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
Overflow page: 6 0 -1 
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
Overflow page: 7 0 -1 
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
Overflow page: 8 0 -1 
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
Overflow page: 9 0 -1 
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
```

So it won't read that, but it'll read this:

```
   0
  0       123                  asd    789.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
  0       345                  zxc    234.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
 -1         x                    x      0.00
```

There's a space right before the -1 and there'd be 2 spaces before the 0.  As shown in the code, I'm trying to print anything with a 0 at the beginning, and skip over the 'header' lines at the front of each hash block.  When I try to force it to print (like print < 3) then it just comes out as garbage symbols.

What it should be doing is printing all records that have a `0` at the beginning and skipping over the headers (because they don't have `-1,0,1` at the beginning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the declaration:

```
char nextIn[3];
```

This code is wrong:

```
if ((fscanf(mioHashFile,"%d",nextIn) == -1) || (fscanf(mioHashFile,"%d",nextIn) == 0) ||
    (fscanf(mioHashFile,"%d",nextIn) == 1))
    {
```

You are passing an array of three characters and expecting `fscanf()` to treat it as an `int`.  Your conditions are odd, too.  EOF is not guaranteed to be `-1` (though I don't recall a system where it was not).  There wouldn't be much point in trying again after detecting EOF (not without other activity to clear the EOF marker).

> When I try this `fscanf(mioHashFile,"%s",nextIn); if (strcmp(nextIn, '-1') == 0)` it still crashes and burns opulently due to type incompatibility. @Emmet also caught my error on the EOF (in that answer's code). How would you do it, and still maintain the `scanf()`, `printf()` formatting that I'm trying to use?

That requires some semi-real coding.  I'd use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` rather than `fscanf()`:

```
char line[4096];
int lineno = 0;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), mioHashFile) != 0)
{
    if (++lineno == 1)
        continue;  // Skip the offset line
    if (line[0] == 'O') // Overflow line - skip
        continue;
    if (sscanf(line, "%d %9s %20s %f", &nDeleteSwitch, sSSN, sName, &nSalary) != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to scan data from: %s", line);
        continue;
    }
    if (nDeleteSwitch == 0)
        printf("%-11s%-21s%-10.2f\n", sSSN, sName, nSalary);
    else if (nDeleteSwitch == -1)
        printf("there's a -1 on row: %d\n", lineno);
    else
        printf("The delete switch value is %d\n", nDeleteSwitch);
}
```

Note that `%s` skips leading white space and then stops scanning at the next white space.

Comment: Interesting.  When I try this `fscanf(mioHashFile,"%s",nextIn);
  if (strcmp(nextIn, '-1') == 0)` it still crashes and burns opulently due to type incompatibility.  @Emmet also caught my error on the EOF (in that answer's code).  How would you do it, and still maintain the `scanf(), printf()` formatting that I'm trying to use?

Comment: I'm such a fan of semi-real coding so +1.  My question is `if (line[0] == 'O') // Overflow line - skip
   continue;
  if (sscanf(line, "%d %9s %20s %f", &nDeleteSwitch, sSSN, sName, &nSalary) != 4)
  {
   fprintf(stderr, "Failed to scan data from: %s", line);
   continue;
  }`  are those 2 conditionals redundant? I mean, that was my intent on the `if <input character at 0> == 'O'` to avoid those header records.

Comment: I don't think the `'O'` conditional is optional, though it depends on your viewpoint.  If you decide that the `!= 4` condition will suffice (so you won't distinguish between an overflow line and a faulty data line), then the `'O'` conditional is optional. I'd rather report the problems separately. I'm not sure where you were scanning for the `'O'`. The `!= 4` conditional is crucial; if you don't test that `sscanf()` got what you expected, you will crash and burn, sooner or later.  Always check that you get the correct return value from any of the `scanf()` family of functions.

Comment: And note that the condition is `!= 4`, testing for anything other than the expected number.  You could get 0, 1, 2 or 3 as well as EOF returned by `sscanf()` — and all those indicate a problem of some sort.  One (major) advantage of the `fgets()` and `sscanf()` approach is that you can report the whole line that caused the trouble — not just the part that's left after `fscanf()` had butchered the first part of the line.  It makes error reporting and recovery easier.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of the detail you supply seems irrelevant to your stated objective of printing out lines that begin with a zero and not printing out the others. The following program, for example, prints out all of the lines that begin with a zero, but no others.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SZ (512)
#define INFILE "datafile.txt"

int main(void) {
    char    buf[BUF_SZ] = {0};
    FILE   *fp;
    long    first;
    char   *endp;

    /* Open input file successfully or bail */
    fp = fopen(INFILE, "r");
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open '%s'\n", INFILE);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Read each line, convert beginning to long and print if it's 0 */
    while( NULL!=fgets(buf, BUF_SZ, fp) && !feof(fp) ) {
        first = strtol(buf, &endp, 10);
        if( first==0L && endp!=buf ) {
            fputs(buf, stdout);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Splendid.  However, `fscanf(mioHashFile,"%d%s%s%f",&nDeleteSwitch,sSSN,sName,&nSalary);
 printf("%-11s%-21s%-10.2f\n",sSSN,sName,nSalary);` is the formatting I posted and the format I need.  Tried using it instead of your `fputs()` but I'm getting wicked garbage output. How could I get my `scanf()` and `printf()` to do what must be done?  Good idea on #define the filename, tho, I use it a zillion other times in the program and should've thought of that. +1

Comment: How do you tell where "ssn" ends and "name" begins? In your sample file, there are no separators that are distinguishable. Is it “fixed character”, i.e. certain fixed ranges on each line correspond to each field. The numbers (11, 21, etc) suggest that, but I can't be sure.

Comment: What do you mean by fixed? The (11,21,etc) is the format of spaces between inputs on each line, there is no `\t` or whatever.  The `scanf()` just pulls in by `int` or `char`, whichever is expected in that order.  Like I said it worked when the file format was like that last file, but then something mysterious happened.

Comment: What I mean is that it seems like the characters 1-3 on every line are the initial integer, then always a space, then 5 to 13 inclusive is the SSN, etc. The “x” shown is in the last position of those fields for which it is shown. Is that about right?